# How to click/tap & swipe right on image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How do I make the following switch from image.png to image2.png when a click/tap & right swipe occurs on image1.png, rather than when a click occurs (like it does currently).

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="image1.png" onclick="this.src='image2.png'">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `I am trying to teach myself JavaScript.` Looks like you ask us to teach you.

Comment: http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/, this librairy will help you to dectect device event in javascript.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following generic method from this [link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents2.shtml). It can detect swipe in all the four directions. You may need to edit the code to suite your needs.

```js
function swipedetect(el, callback){
  
    var touchsurface = el,
    swipedir,
    startX,
    startY,
    distX,
    distY,
    threshold = 150, //required min distance traveled to be considered swipe
    restraint = 100, // maximum distance allowed at the same time in perpendicular direction
    allowedTime = 300, // maximum time allowed to travel that distance
    elapsedTime,
    startTime,
    handleswipe = callback || function(swipedir){}
  
    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        swipedir = 'none'
        dist = 0
        startX = touchobj.pageX
        startY = touchobj.pageY
        startTime = new Date().getTime() // record time when finger first makes contact with surface
        e.preventDefault()
    }, false)
  
    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
        e.preventDefault() // prevent scrolling when inside DIV
    }, false)
  
    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        distX = touchobj.pageX - startX // get horizontal dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
        distY = touchobj.pageY - startY // get vertical dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
        elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime // get time elapsed
        if (elapsedTime <= allowedTime){ // first condition for awipe met
            if (Math.abs(distX) >= threshold && Math.abs(distY) <= restraint){ // 2nd condition for horizontal swipe met
                swipedir = (distX < 0)? 'left' : 'right' // if dist traveled is negative, it indicates left swipe
            }
            else if (Math.abs(distY) >= threshold && Math.abs(distX) <= restraint){ // 2nd condition for vertical swipe met
                swipedir = (distY < 0)? 'up' : 'down' // if dist traveled is negative, it indicates up swipe
            }
        }
        handleswipe(swipedir)
        e.preventDefault()
    }, false)
}
  
//USAGE:
/*
var el = document.getElementById('someel')
swipedetect(el, function(swipedir){
    swipedir contains either "none", "left", "right", "top", or "down"
    if (swipedir =='left')
        alert('You just swiped left!')
})
*/
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18798165)

Comment: @grizzthedj yeah you are right I am editing my post (Y)